# Entity Framework - Inverse Property Relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble understanding how I can accomplish the following relationships:

```
public class Organisation {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Have a single user as an administrator of a company
    public User AdminUser { get; set; }

    // All users associated with the company (including the admin)
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set;}
}

public class User {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Each User must be associated with an Organisation.
    [ForeignKey("Organisation")]
    public Guid OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Is that something that can be done via Inverse Properties? I understand that they are a solution to define multiple relationships between the same entities, but I'm struggling to see how I can set this up for my situation. Could someone help out with example code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a user is never part of multiple organizations and is never admin of multiple organizations, right? Is an admin required to belong to the same organization where he is admin?

Comment: Hi Grek. Yes that is correct. The Organisation acts as an extension of the Admin user, if that makes sense. I don't plan on having M-M relationships between Organisations and Users at this stage.

Comment: What do you mean by *"extension of the Admin user"*? Would you inherit `Organization` from `User` in OOP?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to attribute annotations, you can use fluent configurations. They are more powerful and flexible than the annotations, and allow you to configure multiple relationships between the same entities.

You can define the configurations in the `OnModelCreating` method in your `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
        .HasMany(o => o.Users)
        .WithOne(u => u.Organisation);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
        .HasOne(o => o.AdminUser)
        .WithOne(u => u.Organisation);
}
```

More info on fluent configurations: [here](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api).
 About one-to-many relationships: [here](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration). And about inverse navigation properties: [here](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship#inverse-navigation-property).

Comment: Thanks Diana, I'm currently using Fluent configurations for renaming the Identity tables, and cascading key deletions. Thanks for the example code, I'll give it a go.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer to fix some mistakes, please check the final version..